# Is my own proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I wonder my own proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is correct or rigorous enough, and I also find a proof of the relevant theorem in Tao's Analysis weird. Here is my proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence which is bounded in $[a,b]$. Let $D=\big\{x\in[a,b]~|~[a,x]$ contains infintely many terms of $\{a_n\}\big\}$, in which the predicate "$[a,x]$ contains infintely many terms of $\{a_n\}$" can be transfered into a more rigorous manner, "$\big\{n|a_n\in [a,x]\big\}$ is infinite."

Hence $D=\Big\{x\in[a,b]\Big|\big\{n|a_n\in [a,x]\big\}\text{ is infinite}\Big\}$. Here we first clarify some important observation of $D$. First, is $D$ non-empty? Yes, because $b$ must in $D$. Second, does $D$ have the supremum and infimum? Yes, since $b\in D$ and $a$ is definitely a lower bound of $D$(but not neccessarily in $D$), by the Least Upper Bound property, $D$ has the supremum and infimum. Last, must $D$ have the least element in it? No, for example, if $\{a_n\}$ is defined strictly decreasing and converges to some point $x\in [a,b)$, then $D$ has no least element.

Now we start the proof. Let $x=\inf D$. If $x=a$, the proof is trivial(the subsequence is $a,a,a,a,a,\dotsc$). If $x=b$, the proof is similar to the case $x\in(a,b)$, so I just prove the case $x\in(a,b)$. Because $x$ might not in $D$, so we can't directly conclude that $[a,x]$ contains infinitely many points of $\{a_n\}$. But let $\varepsilon >0$, then $[a,x-\varepsilon]$ must contains finite points of $\{a_n\}$, that is, $\big\{n|a_n\in [a,x-\varepsilon]\big\}$ is finite. By the Approximation Property for Infimum, there also exists a point $y\in D$ such that $x\leq y<x+\varepsilon$, hence $[a,y]$ has infinitely many points of $\{a_n\}$, that is, $\big\{n|a_n\in [a,y]\big\}$ is infinite.

Now we claim that $[a,y]\setminus[a,x-\varepsilon]=(x-\varepsilon,y]$ has infinitely many points of $\{a_n\}$ in a rigorous manner, rather than an intuitive argument. Since $a_n\in [a,x-\varepsilon]\Rightarrow a_n\in [a,y]$, so $\big\{n|a_n\in [a,x-\varepsilon]\big\}\subseteq\big\{n|a_n\in [a,y]\big\}$. So for any $\varepsilon>0$, the difference of an infinite set and finite set, $\big\{a_n|a_n\in(x-\varepsilon,y]\big\}$, is infinite.

We're now going to construct our subsequence. Let $\varepsilon>0$, we can pick an $a_N\in(x-\varepsilon,y]\subsetneq(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$. Next, using $\varepsilon/2>0$, there must exists a $N'>N$ such that  $a_{N'}\in(x-\varepsilon/2,y]\subsetneq(x-\varepsilon/2,x+\varepsilon/2)$. Continuing on this way, we can construct a subsequence, and it is easy to check  that this subsequence converges to $x$, and we omit the detail. $\blacksquare$

Here are my questions.

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Is any part of this proof redundant? Can any part of this proof be simplified?
3. In Terence Tao's Analysis 1, he stated a theorem(Prop. 6.6.6) that any sequence has a subsequence converges to its limit point. He then gave the hint of the proof in the Exercis 6.6.5. He defined a sequence $n_j=\min\{n|a_n\in[L-\frac{1}{j},L+\frac{1}{j}]\}$. Of course, by the Well-Ordering Principle of natural numbers, we know the $\{n_j\}$ is well-defined. However, I think $\{n_j\}$ is not guaranteed to be strictly increasing simply by letting the value of $n_j$ to be the minimum index of $\{a_n\}$ that falled in the interval. (Because, for example, when $j=10$, $a_{100}$ is the mininum-index term in $[L-\frac{1}{10},L+\frac{1}{10}]$, however, when $j=11$, $a_{100}$ is still in $[L-\frac{1}{11},L+\frac{1}{11}]$, so it will be chosen duplicately again.) And we know that in order to make $\{a_{n_j}\}$ to be a so-called "subsequence", $\{n_j\}$ must be strictly increasing. So we can't pick a subsequence like this. Am I correct?
   [image]

**-------------UPDATED---------------**

I made mistakes on discussing the endpoints. Edited like this: if $\inf D=b$, since $b\in D$, then $\inf D\in D$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, $[a,b-\varepsilon]$ has finite points of $\{a_n\}$, hence $[a,b]\setminus[a,b-\varepsilon]=(b-\varepsilon,b]$ has infinitely many point of $\{a_n\}$. So it's easy to construct a subsequence.

If $\inf D=a$, and if $\inf D=a\in D$, then $[a,a]$ has infinitely many points of $\{a_n\}$, so the subsequence is trivially $a,a,a,a,a,\dotsc$. Otherwise if $\inf D=a\not\in D$, then $[a,a]$ has only finite points of $\{a_n\}$. For any $\varepsilon>0$, by the Approximation Property for Infimum, there exists $y\in D$ such that $a\leq y<a+\varepsilon$. So $[a,y]$ has infinitely many point of $\{a_n\}$. Therefore, $[a,y)\setminus[a,a]=(a,y]\subsetneq(a,a+\varepsilon)$ has infinitely many point of $\{a_n\}$, then we can construct the subsequence.

The proof became a bit lengthy. However, I just now came up with a brilliant idea! As my proof stated in the beginning, I suppose the sequence to be in $[a,b]$. Now, we redefine $D$ to be $\mathfrak{D}=\big\{x\in[a-1000,b+1000]~|~[a-1000,x]$ contains infintely many terms of $\{a_n\}\big\}$. Then $\inf\mathfrak{D}$ must not be the endpoint of this new and bigger interval, so we need not to discuss the case when $\inf\mathfrak{D}=a-1000$ or $\inf\mathfrak{D}=b+1000$ anymore!

Comment: If $a =\inf(D)$ it *doesn't* follow that infinitely many terms are equal to $a$. You yourself mentioned the (correct) observation that $\inf(D)$ need not be a member of $D$. On the other hand, your definition of $D$ is clear and it *is* true that $\inf(D)$ is the limit of a convergent subsequence.

Comment: as JohnColeman mentionned, there is a little problem. Actually if you accept that an interval $[x,y] = \emptyset$ if $x > y$ (which is consistent with the definition $[x,y] = \{ z \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \leq z \leq y \}$) and us the word finite as "finite or empty", then I don't think you need a special treatment for the case $x=a$. The rest of the proof seems to be correct, and you also seem to be corrrect about Tao : think $n_j$ should rather be defined as $n_j = min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n > n_{j-1}, |a_n - L| \leq \frac{1}{j} \}$

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm careless with the endpoints. My mistake. :)

Comment: Once you handle the case that $\inf(D) = a$ properly I would say that your proof is not only correct but also rather elegant. You should also do less hand-waiving with the case that the inf is $b$.

Comment: @JohnColeman,  YannHamdaoui It would be very kind of you to help me check my updates and new idea with my proof.

Comment: The fixed proof seems okay. I don't like the your brilliant idea since I think that it obscures the essential idea hence renders the proof more ugly, even if it might make the proof shorter (although this isn't completely clear if you were to eliminate all hand-waving). Brian Scott's suggestion is a good one for stream-lining the proof. Instead of handling the case of $a$ and $b$ separately (hence having a total of 3 cases), his suggestion gets it down to just 2 cases.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is ok. But it's a bit shaky. Bypassing that $x$ need not be in $D$ you may change the Terence condition to an inductive: 
$$ n_{j} = \min\{ n> n_{j-1} \  |  \ a_n\in (L-1/j,L+1/j) \}$$
Then $n_j$ is strictly increasing and $a_{n_j}$ converges. Taking $L=\inf D$ as in your idea will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll answer your last question first. Tao’s hint is just that: a *hint*. It is not the complete solution, even after you after you explain why $\{n\in\Bbb N:|a_n-L|\le 1/j\}$ is non-empty. The final step of the proof will be to show that the sequence $\langle n_j:j\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a strictly increasing subsequence.

As others have noted in the comments, your argument is not quite correct. It can, however, be salvaged, if you consider two cases, $x\in D$ and $x\notin D$. The basic idea is this:

- If $x\notin D$, then $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in[a,x]\}$ is finite, while $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in[a,x+\epsilon]\}$ is infinite for each $\epsilon>0$, so $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in[x,x+\epsilon]\}$ is infinite for each $\epsilon>0$, and you can recursively construct a subsequence converging to $x$ from above.
- If $x\in D$, then $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in[a,x]\}$ is infinite, but $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in[a,x-\epsilon]\}$ is finite for each $\epsilon>0$, so $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\in(x-\epsilon,x]\}$ is infinite for each $\epsilon>0$, and you can recursively construct a subsequence converging to $x$ from below. (You do have to modify this slightly if $x=a$.)

Comment: Thanks! But Tao literally said that "Then consider the subsequence $a_{n_j}$", so I think it may not be the case that Tao left the details to the reader.

Comment: @Eric: He meant exactly what he said: consider it. And when you consider it properly, you realize first (as you did) that it may not actually be a subsequence of the original one, and secondly that it always has a subsequence that *is* a subsequence of the original one. (I will agree that the hint could be worded better. Another alternative is **H. H. Rugh**’s suggested modification.)

Comment: If $x=a$ and if $x\in D$, then it goes to your second case, but the following argument on that may not work. (For example, $[a,x-\varepsilon]$ is undefined and the construction of the subsequence can't also work.) So it seems to have a branch on it?

Comment: @Eric: Of course. I had thought to leave that observation for the OP to make — which you did. I will, however, make it clearer that this is just a sketch.

Comment: Thanks! I was just curious about at least how many cases we need to make in order to prove the B-W theorem.

Comment: @Eric: I think that Tao’s argument, changed slightly as Rugh suggested, is probably about as efficient as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is interesting in that it is easy to see that the resulting limit point is the least limit point of any subsequence in $[a,b]$. You can generalize the idea (outline of proof): Let $c$ be any point in $[a,b]$ (e.g. it could be the midpoint). And define $D$ by:

$$D = \{r > 0 : |c - x_n| < r \rm{\,for \,\, infinitely \,\, many \,\, n} \} $$

Then it is easy to see that $D$ is nonempty (since $b - a \in D$) and it is clearly bounded below. Hence it has an inf. Let $r = \inf(D)$. Then:

Case 1: $r = 0$ (this corresponds to your case where the inf = $a$). It is easy to prove that in this case $c$ is the limit of a convergent subsequence.

Case 2: $r > 0$. This is slightly more complicated than anything in your proof, but by breaking into subcases it is easy enough to see that either $c-r$ or $c+r$ (or both) are limits of convergent subsequences.

In either case the resulting subsequence converges to a point in $[a,b]$ which is as close as possible to $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof breaks down.  Consider the interval [a, b] = [0, 1] and the sequence { 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, ..., n/n+1, ... }.  With respect to this sequence, D as you have defined it is simply { 1 }, and the sub-interval [0, x] is *finite for every x < 1*.

Answer (score 0):

Another style to prove this theorem :Let $I_1=[a,b].$ Let $f(1)=1.$  Define $I_{n+1}$ and $f(n+1)$  inductively for $n\in N$ as follows: The inductive hypothesis is that $$(i).\; I_n \text  { is a closed sub-interval  of } [a,b] \text { of length }\; 2^{1-n}|b-a|,$$ $$(ii).\; n>1\implies  I_n\subset I_{n-1},$$  $$(iii). \;\{m:a_m\in I_n\} \text { is infinite},$$ $$(iv).\;  j\leq n \implies a_j\in I_j,$$   $$(v). \;n>j\geq 1\implies f(n)>f(j).$$   For brevity let $U_n =\max I_n$ and $L_n=\min I_n.$

Now if $\{m:a_m\in [L_n,(L_n+U_n)/2]\}$ is infinite, then let $$I_{n+1}=[L_n,(L_n+U_n)/2].$$ $$ \text {Otherwise let  }\;I_{n+1}=[(L_n+U_n)/2,U_n].$$ In either case let $f(n+1)$ be the least $p\in N$ such that $p>f(n)$ and $a_p\in I_{n+1}.$

Now $f:N\to N$ is strictly increasing so $(a_{f(n)})_n$ is a sub-sequence of $(a_n)_n,$ and it is also a Cauchy sequence because  $n\leq n'<n''\implies$ $ (\;a_{f(n')}\in I_{n'}\subset I_n\; \land \; a_{f(n'')}\in I_{n''}\subset I_n\;)\implies$  $|a_{f(n')}-a_{f(n'')}|\leq U_n-L_n=2^{1-n}|b-a|.$
.